# Continuity of inverse on compact sets.

Tags: general-topology

Problem:

The inverse of a continuous injective function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a compact domain $A \subset  \mathbb{C}$ is also continuous.

**My attempt:**

We want to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous by showing if $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ implies  $x_n \rightarrow x$ **(Is this ok??)**. 
Given that $f$ is continuous, the image of the compact subset $A$ under $f$ will be compact, call this $B$. Consider the sequence $f(x_n) \in B$. Since $B$ is compact there exist a convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(x)$. **I am having a difficult time relating the fact that there exist a convergent subsequence back to the sequence, how do I go back to $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$  from here?**
The continuity of $f$ tell us that given any $\epsilon >0$ and any $x, y \in A$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $ d(x,y) < \delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$.

**Further Ideas**

Since $f$ is continuous, if $x_n \rightarrow x$ then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$. However, I am not sure as to tie this back to the convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_k})$

Comment: Use the definition of continuity: $f^{−1}$ is continuous: whenever $B$ is open then $f(B)$ is open. But instead prove the equivalent statement that whenever $B$ is closed then $f(B)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More general statement. If $f:A\to X$ is a continuous bijection, where $A$ is compact, and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is automatically a homeomorphism. What do we know abut images of compact sets? When are we guaranteed that compact sets are closed?